# Custom attributes added by a custom renderer appears at the wrong HTML elements

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2, renderer

I had to write a custom renderer for `<h:commandLink/>` tag to support `data-*` HTML5 attributes in order to use JSF 2.1 with jQuery mobile framework.

My JSF markup and the output generated by this markup are as follows:

```
          <h:commandLink value="Prev" data-theme="e" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-icon="arrow-l"/>
           <h:commandLink value="Page 1 of 3" data-theme="e" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true"/>
           <h:commandLink value="Next" data-theme="e" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right"/>
```

[image]

It is obvious that my custom renderer properly renders the 2nd and the 3rd `<h:commandLink/>` tags, but not the 1st one. It seems the `data-*` attributes belong to the 1st tag is rendered with the immediate parent `<div/>` tag. This seems a strange (and buggy) behaviour of Mojarra (I use `V 2.1.11`). Please advice me how to overcome this?

My custom renderer code as follows:

```
public class MyCommandLinkRenderer extends CommandLinkRenderer {

    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) {

        String[] attributes = {"data-theme", "data-role", "data-icon", "data-inline", "data-mini", "data-iconpos"};

        ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
        try {
            for (String attribute : attributes) {
                String value = (String) component.getAttributes().get(attribute);
                if (value != null) {
                    writer.writeAttribute(attribute, value, attribute);
                    System.out.println(attribute + " " + value);
                }
            }
            super.encodeBegin(context, component);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you configured the new Renderer class in the faces-config.xml element <render-kit>? I'm wondering what component-family and renderer-type should be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must call `super.encodeBegin()` **before** writing the attributes.

Otherwise you're writing the attributes to the previous HTML element, as confirmed by the generated HTML output. The `super.encodeBegin()` starts the new HTML element.

This is just a bug in your own code, not in Mojarra.

---

**Update**: also, overriding the `encodeBegin()` was not right in first place. You should rather be overriding the `LinkRenderer#writeCommonLinkAttributes()` method.

```
@Override
protected void writeCommonLinkAttributes(ResponseWriter writer, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
    super.writeCommonLinkAttributes(writer, component);

    // ...
}
```

It does by the way then not matter if you call `super` before or after your job.

Comment: If calling super.encodeBegin() before writing the attributes, tag attributes are irregularly rendered (some attributes are rendered but some are not, some attributes from one tag rendered with another)

Comment: I see, the `CommandLinkRenderer` is designed a bit differently. You should be overriding the `writeCommonLinkAttributes()` instead of the `encodeBegin()`. Then it doesn't matter if you call `super` first or last.

Comment: Yes, it is working by overriding CommandLinkRenderer(). Thanks very much BalusC!

Comment: I made a similar effort to create custom renderer for '<h:commandButton/>' tag as well. But the ButtonRenderer hierarchy ('Renderer<---HtmlBacicRenderer<---ButtonRenderer') does not seem to have a suitable method to override. Any suggestions? In general how may we spot the method to override when adding custom attributes to any of the existing JSF tags? (any documentations / articles etc.?)