# Custom head renderer attributes not being passed through

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I'm trying to render a `head` element with a `prefix` attribute. In order to do this in JSF:

```xml
<h:head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# XXXX: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/XXXX#">
```

I created a custom `head` renderer:

```java
public class FacebookHeadRenderer extends HeadRenderer{
    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context, UIComponent component)
            throws IOException {
        ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
        writer.startElement("head", component);
        RenderKitUtils.renderPassThruAttributes(context,
                                                writer,
                                                component,
                                                HEAD_ATTRIBUTES);
        System.out.println("FacebookHeadRenderer!");
    }

    private static final Attribute[] HEAD_ATTRIBUTES;
    static {
        Attribute[] baseAttributes = AttributeManager.getAttributes(
                AttributeManager.Key.OUTPUTHEAD);
        HEAD_ATTRIBUTES = new Attribute[baseAttributes.length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < baseAttributes.length; ++i) {
            HEAD_ATTRIBUTES[i] = baseAttributes[i];
        }
        HEAD_ATTRIBUTES[HEAD_ATTRIBUTES.length - 1] = Attribute.attr("prefix");
    }
}
```

and registered it in `faces-config.xml`:

```xml
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>javax.faces.Output</component-family>
        <renderer-type>javax.faces.Head</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.localgp.jsf.FacebookHeadRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

`FacebookRenderer` is being called (verified by `FacebookHeadRenderer!` being printed), yet the `prefix` attribute is not rendered.

Just as a sanity check, I added the `lang` attribute:

```xml
<h:head lang="en_AU"
        prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# XXXX: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/XXXX#">
```

and all I got was

```html
<head lang="en_AU">
```

Ideas?

Comment: This isn't necessary with [JSF 2.2](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jsf-2_2-fr-eval-spec/index.html), section 10.1.4, Pass Through Attributes.

Answer (score 3):

Well it seems I'm [supposed to call `super.encodeBegin(context, component)` first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11986014/584670). (Thanks BalusC.)

So I modified the renderer:

```java
public class FacebookHeadRenderer extends HeadRenderer {
    private static final Attribute[] EXTRA_HEAD_ATTRIBUTES =
            { Attribute.attr("prefix") };

    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context, UIComponent component)
            throws IOException {
        super.encodeBegin(context, component);
        ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
        RenderKitUtils.renderPassThruAttributes(context,
                                                writer,
                                                component,
                                                EXTRA_HEAD_ATTRIBUTES); }
```

}

It works now.